# Does Angular 2 use Shadow DOM or a Virtual DOM?

Tags: angular, shadow-dom, virtual-dom

What does Angular 2 use to update the DOM. Is it Shadow DOM or Virtual DOM ? Was there any such concept in Angular 1?

Answer (score 49):

**update**

Shadow DOM is now directly supported.

**original**

Angular2 doesn't use **shadow DOM** (default) nor **virtual DOM**.

With `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default) there is no **shadow DOM** because style encapsulation is only emulated.

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` enables **shadow DOM** on browsers that support it natively or it's again emulated when the webcomponents polyfill is loaded.

**Shadow DOM** is also not targeting performance as virtual DOM is, but style encapsulation.

Angular2 doesn't use **virtual DOM** at all.

Angular2 has change detection that detects changes to the model and only updates the parts of the DOM that need to be changed according to the model changes.

For more details see also [Is Shadow DOM fast like Virtual DOM in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012239/is-shadow-dom-fast-like-virtual-dom-in-react-js/36906251#36906251)

Comment: See what is [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) on the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) in the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/)

Comment: Just popping 'round to say the Angular 2 *can* use the Shadow DOM, it just doesn't by default: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

Comment: @drhayes thanks for the update. Glad to hear this finally became available.

Comment: **Update:** `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` is now deprecated since Angular 6.0.8, and is replaced by `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53806584/7918037 and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11526

Answer (score 4):

**React and Vue are using Virtual DOM and Angular use direct DOM rendering system.**

It's the same thing that Angular did with version 1.x, but it is optimized and there is a surprise for you :)

It is much faster to work with JavaScript objects than with DOM, because nothing drown on screen

Comment: Angular does actually use Shadow DOM

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2** and the version came after doesn't use **Virtual DOM** instead it uses change detection mechanism to detect any change and act upon it while **React** and **Vue** uses **Virtual DOM** to compare with the **Real DOM** to detect any change occurred.

On the other hand in some way **Angular** does uses **[Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)** in **encapsulation** to keep the markup structure, style, and behaviour hidden and separate from other code or components on the page so that different parts do not clash. you can learn more about encapsulation [here](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

And the last part there is no such concept of **Virtual DOM** and **Shadow DOM** used in **Angular 1** or **AngularJS**.