# ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom vs ViewEncapsulation.Native

Tags: angular

when trying to change encapsulation 4 options appear Emulated, Native, None, and finally new one "ShadowDom". I know `ViewEncapsulation.Native` for use Shadow DOM.

### [image: available options for encapsulation]

so what're benefits from using `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation), `Native` is now deprecated in favor of `ShadowDOM` implementation. The reason for the change is that the `Native` ViewEncapsulation uses the deprecated version of ShadowDOM, and the new one uses the current version of the standard. (For the browsers that support it).

Comment: Since ShadowDOM is implemented by all major browsers, why is Emulated still the default?

Comment: I think partially to not break backward compatibility, but for the most part, because IE can't support ShadowDOM. That, size of polyfills required, means that the default option would be suboptimal for a significant portion of users.