# What relation is there between Angular's <ng-content> and ShadowDOM

Tags: html, angular, shadow-dom

While comparing Angular Content Projection using `<ng-content>` with HTML's ShadowDOM ([ShadowDOM Visualizer](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/shadowdom-visualizer/index.html)), I found a subtle difference.

In the above mentioned link page, when I remove `select` attribute of `<content>` in `<header>` tag, then all other contents are attached to header component.

While in Angular, only elements having no selector are collected and appended to the wildcard `<ng-content></ng-content>`

I got technically nostalgic while viewing the above link. So, this question came in my mind.

**Note**: I am redirected to that link from Google Developer's Web Fundamentals on Shadow DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your question!

I think there is no relation between Angular and ShadowDOM by default. If you use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which is set **by default** angular will emulate the ShadowDOM. You can enable it with `ViewEncapsulation.Native`, but only in browsers that support this feature.

You could check [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw1lqc) with DevTools. You will find these weird `_ngcontent-pmu-c51` attributes. 
It's the way how angular emulates the ShadowDOM.

I hope I found an answer to your question. I'm looking forward to your feedback.

You can find more info here:

[Code documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

[Good blog post about the view encapsulation](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

[The similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739648/does-angular-2-use-shadow-dom-or-a-virtual-dom)

**Update:**

We don't have any relation between the Angular `<ng-content>` and ShadowDOM. Maybe, they have some similar concepts, but it's a maximum.

Comment: Sorry. This is not answer to my question. Please review link in my question and relate it with <ng-content> behaviour.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your question correctly. Just to clarify. Do you want to know what is the "scope" of the styles of the elements that would be attached to the `<ng-content>` element and in the what way they are connected with the shadow DOM?

Comment: Not related with the styles but with actual element projection concept. Please review how example mentioned in question works by doing some tweaks with it.